# Software To Preview .eml Files In Browser

Tags: browser, preview

So I am looking for a software that allows you to preview .eml files in browser rather than giving you a prompt to download them.  Does anyone know of something that could do this?

Answer (score 0):

Upload the email file on this URL,

http://www.encryptomatic.com/viewer/

You can view the file.

Answer (score -1):

You can set this using PreviewConfig tool [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/previewconfig-tool-registers-file-types-for-the-preview-pane-in-windows-vista/). You can set eml files to be viewed in Preview windows as type text thus:

```
Preview Handler information:

GUID        : {1531d583-8375-4d3f-b5fb-d23bbd169f22}
Description : Windows TXT Previewer
Module name : C:\Windows\system32\shell32.dll
```